# NSXPCInterface constructor does not recognise protocol in Swift

Tags: xcode, protocols, xpc, swift2, nsxpcconnection

I'm creating a XPC service in swift, and I created my protocol:

```
protocol MyProtocol {

func myFunc()

}
```

When I try to set the interface that the exported object implements (in my main.swift), by initialising a new object of NSXPCInterface with protocol, I get an error:

```
/// This method is where the NSXPCListener configures, accepts, and resumes a new incoming NSXPCConnection.
func listener(listener: NSXPCListener, shouldAcceptNewConnection newConnection: NSXPCConnection) -> Bool {
    // Configure the connection.
    // First, set the interface that the exported object implements.
    newConnection.exportedInterface = NSXPCInterface(MyProtocol)
```

Error is: Cannot convert value of type '(MyProtocol).Protocol' (aka 'MyProtocol.Protocol') to expected argument type 'Protocol'

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reference the protocol's type, you need to use `.self` on it:

```
 newConnection.exportedInterface = NSXPCInterface(withProtocol: MyProtocol.self)
```

You also have to add `@objc` to your protocol declaration:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),it will be useful to help you to raise your content quality